# How to to query multiple foreign key related objects of multiple objects Django 1.8

Tags: django

Can't figure out how to to query multiple foreign key related objects of multiple objects.
Modals:

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    who_did = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile', related_name='who_did_NOTIFICATION', blank=True)
```

Views. Objects are fine:

```
objects = Notification.objects.all()
profiles = objects.select_related('who_did').all()
```

Also tried :

```
profiles = objects.prefetch_related().all()
```

And:

```
profiles = objects.select_related.all()
```

How to handle it correctly in Django 1.8?

Comment: Please paste the while model (`creation_date`. `whom`...)

Comment: @Udi they don't matter. I 'v even edited the question

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "up vote
1
down vote
favorite
Can't figure out how to to query multiple foreign key related objects of multiple objects"? I am not sure what you are trying top do. Please provide an example of data.

Comment: @Udi I am trying to get related foreign key objects as objects in order to json them and send via ajax to view, because otherwise I would not be able to fetch required data in view (like it can be done using templates code)

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

```
ids = [123, 456, 789]

qs = Notification.objects.filter(id__in=ids)
for o in qs:
    print(o.id)
    for n in o.who_did_NOTIFICATION.all():    
        print("*", n.id)
```

Comment: @Udi I have also implemented it via python, although I don't really understand you code  . The question was  how to do via django queryset and objects

Comment: What do you mean in "via django queryset and objects"?